# Why would the active state of my links not work?

Tags: css

This is my CSS to change the default settings of the color of my menu links:

```
.main-header-menu a {
color: #ffffff !important;
}

.main-header-menu a:hover {
color: #8feaff !important;
}

.main-header-menu a:active {
color: #8feaff !important;
}
```

All very standard and very normal - yet for some reason the :active state does NOT change.

Can you see any reason why not? I was hoping it would change to #8feaff as written above.

Thanks

Comment: The `:active`  selector is used to select and style the active link.

A link becomes active when you click on it.

Comment: if you want to know if the user visited the link then use `:visited`

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed, that is what I meant - I click on the active link, so for example > from home to contact and on contact page the link should change color for "active" but with above code no change...

Answer (score 0):

The `:active` selector is used to select and style the active link. A link becomes active when you click on it.
if you want The :active selector is used to select and style the `active` link. A link becomes active when you click on it. 
 
if you want to apply style if visited the link then use `visited`.

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
a:visited{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no :active state in CSS. You should add .active class

```css
body{
background: black;
}

.main-header-menu{
display: inline-block}
.main-header-menu a {
color: #ffffff !important;
}

.main-header-menu a:hover {
color: #8feaff !important;
}

.main-header-menu a.active {
color: #8feaff !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
<div class="main-header-menu"> <a class="">menu</a> </div>
<div class="main-header-menu"> <a class="active">menu</a> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There most certainly is an :active state in CSS.